# How to show pop up in table validation in angular JS

Tags: angularjs

what should I use for displaying faculty Id is needed pop up box during validation of data inside tables. If I am not entering faculty Id then it shouldn't get added and should show that message.

```
        <table ng-form name="myForm">
            <tr>
                <td>Faculty ID</td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="faculty.id" required/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Faculty Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="faculty.name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Faculty Salary:</td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="faculty.salary" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><button ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" ng-click="addfaculty(faculty)">ADD</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: even if  you correct the typo i think it will not be disabled unless you make one of the input required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you made a typo:) 
ng-disbaled
should be ng-disabled

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
<table ng-form name="myForm">
            <tr>
                <td>Faculty ID</td>
                <td ><input type="text" ng-model="faculty.id" required/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Faculty Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="faculty.name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Faculty Salary:</td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="faculty.salary" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><button ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" ng-click="addfaculty(faculty)">ADD</button></td>
            </tr>
</table>
```